# Noarg constructor is not getting created

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I configured `kotlin-noarg` plugin in my `Spring` application:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        kotlinVersion = '1.2.51'
    }
    dependencies {
        // ...
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-noarg:${kotlinVersion}"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: "kotlin-noarg"

noArg {
    annotation("com.example.demo.DefaultConstructor")
    invokeInitializers = true
}
```

Then I have my annotation declared:

```
package com.example.demo

@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.CLASS)
annotation class DefaultConstructor
```

And then I have my class:

```
@DefaultConstructor
data class UserForm(@field:NotNull
                    @field:DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm") val dateTime: LocalDateTime)
```

Here is how I'm trying to use `UserForm` class:

```
@GetMapping("")
public String userForm(UserForm userForm) {
    userForm.copy(LocalDateTime.now());
    return "/users/form";
}
```

So `Spring` is trying here to initialize my `UserForm` class using reflection, but there is no default constructor being generated, despite `kotlin-noarg` plugin being configured(correctly, I believe).

Where is the problem here ? Is it because of misconfiguration of the `kotlin-noarg` plugin ? And how to fix it ?

I created [demo project](https://github.com/alexbezhan/localdatetime-binding-error)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fully sure with the answer but:

1. `kotlin-noarg` provides a syntactic constructor(only available with reflection)
2. If spring is trying to instantiate `UserForm` directly (without reflection) it will fail.
3. There is a way to avoid the problem.
   Mark `UserForm` as `@Entity` after this it will be recognized as something that belongs to spring. After this no-arg constructor will be either generated by `kotlin-spring` plugin or you need to add `kotlin-jpa` plugin